# What is the difference between .NET's HMAC and HMAC KeyedHashAlgorithm?

Tags: c#, .net, hash, f#, cryptography

What is the difference between `Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256.Create()` and `Security.Cryptography.KeyedHashAlgorithm.Create("HmacSHA256")`?

Comment: Heh, good one. Could be part of a riddle book for C# or an obfuscated C# contest :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, about `Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256.Create()` --

`Create` method is the method of `HMAC` class, from which `HMACSHA256` is derived. In short:

```
public class HMACSHA256 : HMAC {
...
}
```

where `HMAC` is defined as:

```
public abstract class HMAC : KeyedHashAlgorithm {
    new static public HMAC Create () {
        return Create("System.Security.Cryptography.HMAC");
    }

    new static public HMAC Create (string algorithmName) {
        return (HMAC) CryptoConfig.CreateFromName(algorithmName);
    }
    ...
}
```

---

Second, about `Security.Cryptography.KeyedHashAlgorithm.Create("HmacSHA256")`

```
public abstract class KeyedHashAlgorithm : HashAlgorithm { 
    new static public KeyedHashAlgorithm Create(String algName) {
        return (KeyedHashAlgorithm) CryptoConfig.CreateFromName(algName);    
    }
    ...
}
```

---

As you can see, both calls result in calling `CryptoConfig.CreateFromName` method, but with different parameter values, i.e., `System.Security.Cryptography.HMAC` in first case, and `HmacSHA256` in second case. Internally, there are some tables and reflection logic inside [`CryptoConfig.CreateFromName`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/cryptoconfig.cs,6378ebce6e2ab452) method.

The result of first call is `SHA1` hash, and the result of second  call is `SHA256`.

Comment: Thanks! So why is it that the classes `HMACSHA256` and `HMACSHA1` both return `SHA1` hashes?

Comment: @chaaru Because `CryptoConfig.CreateFromName` doesn't know anything about `SHA256`, it receives `System.Security.Cryptography.HMAC` as input and thus it creates default one for `HMAC` algorithm, which is `SHA1`.

Comment: Heh, in Java you would get a (configurable) warning or error if you could call `Create` without specifying the declaring class. Isn't that also the case in the VisualStudio IDE and command line compilers for .NET? This sounds like a recipe for failure to me.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I couldn't force compiler to generate warning for that. The only thing in VS2015 is that it offers to simplify `HMACSHA256.Create` to `HMAC.Create`.

Comment: That's at least something I suppose. Thanks for checking this out; hopefully that will prevent others from having to search for the same option. If anybody is writing static code analyzers for C#; this one should be in there.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing. `Security.Cryptography.KeyedHashAlgorithm.Create("HmacSHA256")` ([reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/cryptoconfig.cs,6378ebce6e2ab452,references))  uses reflection to lookup `Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256`.

Comment: This would probably be the case if the `HMACSHA256` class did "override" the static `Create` method.